# Adding PHP Extensions using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to setup a local development environment in docker that includes nginx and php. I started with [this tutorial](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/) and have a functioning server. My project requires that a couple PHP extensions be installed, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to adapt this setup to include them.

The documentation for the image says to put it in a dockerfile, which I have done. However, that gives me an error of:

> ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
>   Service php has both an image and alternate Dockerfile. A service can either be built to image or use an existing image, not both.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  dockerfile: extensions
  image: php:7-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
```

My `extensions` file

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable zip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd
```

Clearly I'm going about this wrong. Is there a way to install the extensions into this image, or do I need to create my own? I'm using Docker for Windows.

Comment: you have to build the image yourself, if you use `image:` in compose file it never read the Dockerfile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `extensions` file, add this to the top:
`FROM php:7-fpm`

and remove the `image: php:7-fpm` from your docker-compose file

Answer (score 13):

this is my code. its already running on my server.

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  #remove this
  #dockerfile: extensions
  #image: php:7-fpm
  #change with build ...
  build: './docker/php'
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
```

Then, add `Dockerfile` file to the `docker/php` folder:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
        intl
```

Now you can run Dockerfile inside docker-compose.